# Why can't a triangular matrix with only zeros in its diagonal be invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

Why can't a triangular matrix with only zeros in its diagonal be invertible?

I know that it is not invertible but I don't know well the reasons, perhaps. Actually, I read that can't have any zero in its diagonal, in order to be invertible.

In general, I know that if a matrix has an inverse, the product of that matrix with its inverse is equal to the identity matrix, namely, with a matrix with 1s as its diagonal.

Comment: Can you state precisely, which matrix are you talking about. The first sentence is misleading

Comment: hollow matrix, it is called, if I am not wrong. A matrix which has 0s in its diagonal.

Comment: @Ulysses, sorry, you right. I mean a triangular matrix with 0s in its diagonal.

Comment: Laplace expansion can yield that such matrix determinant is zero, thus it's uninvertible. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A upper triangular matrix with 0's on its diagonal has its first column filled with 0's. Therefore its determinant is 0, which means it is not invertible. For a lower triangular matrix, the same holds with the last column.

In case you're not familiar with determinants:When A is upper triangular, let's suppose $A^{-1}$ exists. Then $A^{-1}A=I$. Let $B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\\0\\...\\0 \end{pmatrix}$. Then $AB=0$. However, $(A^{-1}A)B=I B=B$ , but $$A^{-1}(AB)=A^{-1}0=0\ne B$$  We have a contradiction, therefore A is not invertible.

Comment: Can we find another way to state it, without referring to the determinant? Just because I am not sure if the determinant was already treated in the course. PS. I mean, I am almost sure that it was not introduced yet the determinant.

Comment: Edited the answer

Answer (score 5):

(The original question did not ask for a triangular matrix)

There are (many) invertible matrices with a zero diagonal, for example consider the matrix 
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
then $$ A^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
so $A$ is invertible with $A^{-1} = A$.

---

Addendum: For the reformultated question, note that a triangular matrix with zero diagonal, has a zero column. Hence its kernel is not trivial, therefore it is not invertible.

Comment: Sorry, @Ulysses was right. I did not specify that I refer to a triangular matrix.

Comment: @Alwayslearning Corrected.

Answer (score 4):

This is not true, as $\left(\begin{array}{c c}0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right)$ is invertible.

Comment: Sorry, @Ulysses was right. I did not specify that I refer to a triangular matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the best version I could think of completely avoiding advanced concepts like kernels, determinants and the like.

Any matrix that has a row or column which is a zero vector cannot be inverted. If we have
$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
-&a_1&-\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
-&a_n&-
\end{pmatrix}
\text{ and }
B=
\begin{pmatrix}
|&\cdots&|\\
b_1&\cdots&b_n\\
|&\cdots&|
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with $a_i=0$ for some $i$, then $a_i\cdot b_i=0$ making entry $(A\cdot B)_{i,i}=0$, so their product cannot be the identity matrix. Knowing that inverses are always two-sided, similar considerations work for the column vector case.

---

Now a triangular matrix with zeros on its main diagonal has both a zero row and a zero column, and the statement follows.